# Geolocation is so slow! what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

this is my simple code I'm using in a test page: but it takes ages to find the address...how come? am i doing something wrong?

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=it&amp;file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=*xxxxxx*" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var geocoder;

    function addAddressToMap(response) 
    {
      if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) 
      {
        alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode that address");
      } 
      else 
      {
        place = response.Placemark[0];
        point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1], place.Point.coordinates[0]);

        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = place.address;
      }
    }


    function searchGeolocation() 
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation) 
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
            {  
                geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
                document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
                document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
                coordinates = position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;
                geocoder.getLocations(coordinates, addAddressToMap);

            }); 
        }else
        {
            document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = "Unknown";
            document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = "Unknown";
            document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = "Unknown";
            alert("I'm sorry, but geolocation services are not supported by your browser.");    
        }
    }



</script>


<br/>
latitude = <div id="latitude">loading...</div>
<br/>
longitude = <div id="longitude">loading...</div>
<br/>
address = <div id="address">loading...</div>
<br/>


<script type="text/javascript">

    searchGeolocation();

</script>
```

Comment: How long is it taking? I assume you're not doing a large number of lookups at once?

Comment: @Shawn: The `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` bit: http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/ Yes, the terminology is a bit imprecise, but it's clear what's meant.

Comment: Finding GPS location can take a minute, if GPS signal isn't clear (between high buildings etc.)

Answer (score 12):

Well - it's actually doing geolocation!

To speed it up, consider providing the extra parameters for utilising cached results, and a timeout.

Comment: Most practical advice on this question

Comment: You can view those extra parameters over here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions - in my case this did not make a difference though.

Answer (score 5):

I've been struggling with that for a couple of hours now and it turned out that it is a different result for each browser aka it is something that code can't fully control but you can do some progress by adding these options to `getlocation.getCurrentPosition` function call:

```
enableHighAccuracy: false,
timeout: 5000,
maximumAge: Infinity
```

You can read more about the meaning of each option [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions)

To get a sense of benchmarks using Chrome:

```
enableHighAccuracy: true // ~3997ms
enableHighAccuracy: false // ~84ms
```

**Note:** the first time each of these is called, it's still approximately 3.9 seconds. Each subsequent call can be reduced by using the `maximumAge` or removing `enableHighAccuracy`.

Comment: it helps me, tks bro <3

Answer (score 2):

Check your mobile device's Location service mode. Make sure the accuracy is in High status on your devide. The High accuracy mode uses GPS, WIFI or Mobile network to find the location.

If you choose Low or GPS only mode it takes forever.

Also play with the geo location option and give the timeout and cache options.

Comment: Shouldn't this be other way around? Is it correct that high precision takes less than low precision?

Comment: @Alpha - High precision is more accurate and can provide more frequent updates on mobile devices. The advantage of low precision is it preserves battery life. Also, on newer Android phones such as Samsung S6 I get update rate of about 1 Hz. On an older phone it is less frequent.

Comment: @kashiraja Just to make sure I get it right: the post claims using GPS is slow. It also claims that using GPS+mobile network+WiFi is fast. Is that correct? If it is, I imagine WiFi+mobile network provide inaccurate results first and the finally GPS is updated. Otherwise, I cannot figure out why using more resources would give a faster result.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. 

When I turn on `enableHighAccuracy: true`, it takes ~3997ms for the API call to go through. Whereas, `enableHighAccuracy: false` finishes in ~84ms.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of your calls might take some seconds to finish, for example `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` takes up to 5 sec (when working) for me in Safari.